# Magento 2.4.2: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return customer().fullname }" Message: Unable to parse bindings

Tags: magento2, frontend, knockoutjs, html

The following error is found during the process of upgrading Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4 in console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return customer().fullname }"
Message: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: html:
```

I found out that this error is being caused by this line.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
<span class="not-logged-in" data-bind="html: '<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
<?= $block->getBlockHtml('header.additional') ?>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The full `header.phtml` file containing this code is below

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 */
$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>
<?php if ($block->getShowPart() == 'welcome') : ?>
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span class="logged-in"
              data-bind="text: new String('<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().fullname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span class="not-logged-in" data-bind="html: '<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('header.additional') ?>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php elseif ($block->getShowPart() == 'other') :?>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Look like your code is fine but not sure why you are facing an error. This is core code in header.phtml file as well.

Comment: Yes, also I verified the contents of the file with those of the file header.phtml in the live site. I'm getting this error on the staging site. Everything looks identical. Please pay a deeper look into this issue to help me.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, this one is fixed. I got another error in the product page. Kindly have a look at it please. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358362/magento-2-4-4-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you check if the customer is logged in before you process the logic that requests the customer information.

This answer might be helpful to implement it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203955/16416