# Magento 2.4.4: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseOldPrice')

Tags: magento2

I just upgraded Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4. In product pages, I noticed an error that I'm sure is not because of any customization done in the site. Could you please help me find solutions to this?

```
configurable.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseOldPrice')
    at configurable.js:46:34
    at Function.each (underscore.js:1335:17)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._calculatePrice (configurable.js:45:19)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._calculatePrice (widget.js:132:25)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.<anonymous> (configurable.js:591:39)
    at underscore.js:723:29
    at Function.each (underscore.js:1330:17)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._getPrices (configurable.js:588:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._getPrices (widget.js:132:25)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._reloadPrice (configurable.js:575:77)
```